# Can´t download Android packages through SDK and AVD Manager any more

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

That´s the error message:

```
 Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 8
 File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\platform-tools_r08-windows.zip (Access denied)
```

When i look into my "temp" folder, it´s empty..

What´s the problem here?

Comment: Have you updated the SDK tools to the version released today? If yes, restart them.

Comment: i tried to download the "Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 8" in order to be able to download the new android SDK... but suddendly this error appears

Comment: Hey try to change the location from program files to other location,it may help you,im not sure..I thought problem with directory permissions..

Comment: Ok it was the problem with the permissions.. But how could that be? It´s my own computer and I´m logged in as administrator.

Answer (score 7):

Running "SDK Manager.exe" as administrator should solve your problem. That worked for me.

Comment: Access to folders under Program Files and Program Files (x86) is for elevated (admin) apps only. Either move the folder as @ZalnT suggests, or elevate the download process as in this answer. I prefer this one because it leaves your machine in a normal and protected state afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to help to move it to another folder, I just moved the directory C:\Program (x86)\Android to C:\Android.
Using Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your directory from C drive.It sometime happened with me so that i changed the Location of Android Sdk & tools because there is a possibility of window crasehd due to some uncertain reason so you will have to download all that Platform tools data again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do following thing:

- Install updated SDK.exe
- Right click on SDK/AVD manager to Run as Administrator for plugins

Hope it may short out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is old question but still actual and unconfirmed (unsolved).

SDK Manager creates sdk/temp folder and tries to copy there library archive files. So permissions are problem. You can either change permissions to a sdk folder, move SDK to another location or run SDK manager.exe as administrator.

If one choose the latter option:
Go to \sdk\tools folder, find and run android.bat, which does everything in the safest way (gathers and sets what it needs and run from temp folder). I even don't think that running just SDK_Manager.exe will work.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are not the Problem. I had the same problem using Windows 8, and I looked into the .bat files to see whats the problem. "android.bat" uses the xcopy command to copy the libraries it uses into the temp folder. But the xcopy command is stored in the System32 folder. Edit android.bat and replace "xcopy" with "C:\Windows\System32\xcopy". That solved it for me, my temp folder did what it was supposed to do, and if I run SDK using the shell, I dont get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Permission is the problem.
Do this

1. First Right Click on the Android Sdk Directoory

   2.Choose properties
2. Go To security Tab  And click the Edit Button.(you need to be Administrator to do this)

   4.Click the Add Button

   5. type "Everyone" in the Enter object Name box And click "Check Names".
   6. Then Click Ok
   7. Now select "everyone" in user names Box And give it Full control in Permissions Box.
   8. Click ok & again Ok to exit.

(: Now you will not need to run SDK Manager as administrator everytime